# jquery onmouseover of an image/link shows a div at the same position (tooltip)

Tags: jquery, hover, containers, tooltip

i want hover over an image -> which is in an link

during i'm over the image should popup (like a tooltip) an div, which i can fill also with some stuff - any idea?!

$this is the link which includes an img:
i found the image within and wanted to span a div above the image and make some jquery effects which lets the user get the info, that clicking the image wil enlarge it

```
        $(this).parent().append($("<div/>")
                        .css({ "display" : "block", "left" : img.x, "top" : img.y,  
                            "width" : img.width, "heigth" : img.heigth, "border" : "1px solid red"})
                        .text("Click me!")
```

does not work :-/

Comment: please expand a little bit on what you want... do you want a form to pop up or just an informational div?

Comment: @Jason would it matter whether the div had stuff inside it or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a tooltip function, there are quiet a few tooltip plugins already available, even with custom content, text, formatted text, custom layout, or even ajax content.

take a look at one of these plugins:

- [Qtip plugin: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)
- [jQuery plugin tooltip: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/)
- [SimpleTip: http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/](http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/)
- [ClueTip: http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/)
- [wTooltip: http://wayfarerweb.com/wtooltip.php](http://wayfarerweb.com/wtooltip.php)

some have more options than the other, i used simpletip for some site and its great 
though its limited contentwise, what you want is probably more something like Qtip

Comment: i do not wanted any plugin only the core lib :-S

Comment: i'd go for the plugin if the plugin is well written (most of the time i'd find a way to do it myself but twice as long as the plugin did it)... but i can understand if you want to achieve this on your own.